# After upgrading cordova version from 8.x.x to 9.0.0 cordova build is failing

Tags: cordova, cordova-9.0.0

On updating the cordova to 9.0.0 version, cordova build is failing with the below error

Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'properties-parser'
Unhandled error. (The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.)

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me and the only way to solve it was to reset the entire project.

> 1- Delete hooks, platform, nodes_modules, plugins folder, package.json and package-lock.json
>
> 2- Add a platform

This should re-add everything to your project properly. "Upgrading" is not truly supported with Cordova, lots of things breaking.

Comment: i have done this multiple times but issue still persists

Comment: I think there should be some proper solution for this

Comment: This is the only way to solve it. If it does not work that means some of your plugins might not be compatible.

Comment: I found the root cause of this issue. Please check https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/issues/498